# Google earth engine export to Drive not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, export, landsat, libgee

```
var roi = geometry;

Map.addLayer (roi);`enter code here`
var start = ee.Date ('2013-12-01')
var finish = ee.Date('2013-12-30');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').filterDate('2013-12-01', '2013-12-30');

var Lagos = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate(start, finish)
.sort('CLOUD_COVER', false);

var count = Lagos.size();
print ('Lagos view', count);

var best = ee.Image(Lagos.sort ('CLOUD_COVER').first());

print ('lagos view', best);

var trueColour = {
  bands:["SR_B4", "SR_B3", "SR_B2"],
  min:5000,
  max:12000
};

Map.centerObject( roi, 12);

Map.addLayer(Lagos, trueColour, "true-colour image");

Export.image.toDrive({image:dataset,
   description:"Rawscene",
   region:roi,
   scale:30
});
```

When I run it, it returns an error code 3. How can I fix it ?